# Angular html nesting

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Let's say I have in some upper level class some angular template code that looks like this

```
    <outer-component>
        <a></a>
    </outer-component>
```

Where `<a>` can be any module that extends a certain interface defined elsewhere, is there a way for `<outer-component>` be able to take `<a>` or whatever is placed inside the tags and communicate with it specifically be able to listen to functions or bind to variables in a way that is as succinct as the snippet above?

Comment: To me it sounds like *can you define a variable in javascript*. I'm normally not one of those but RTFM is the answer here

Comment: I get that right, but this is more of a design principle thing, can I write a wrapper class that allows for something like this to be able to happen? I've read the manual I just need some help getting my mind around having html nesting as a way to communicate between these children

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data between a parent and a child (hierarchical relationship) you can use `EventEmitter` to allow the parent to get data from the child.

In the child component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from 'angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: `
        <h3>Child</h3>
        Say {{message}}
        <button (click)="sendMessage()"></button>
    ´,
    styleUrls: ['pathToStyles.css']
 })

export class ChildComponent {

    message: string = "Hello world";

    @Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor() {}

    sendMessage() {
        this.messageEvent.emit(this.message);
    }
}
```

In the parent component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
     selector: 'app-parent',
     template: `
     Message: {{message}}
          <app-child (messageEvent)="receiveMessage($event)"></app-child>
          `,
     styleUrls: ['pathToStyles.css']
})

export class ParentComponent {

    constructor() { }

    message:string;

    receiveMessage($event) {
        this.message = $event
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Juan but this doesn't fully answer my question, so the child is variable in this case and the parent is receiving the child from a superparent do I have access to these children in the parent from only the html definition above?

Comment: As far as I know, components can´t access another components no matter if they are nested. So you need to use something like EventEmitter, ViewChild() or a service.

Comment: that's what I feared hopefully someone else knows some magic about this, thank you though